# How to get html input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the code below in a html form:
`<input type="text" name="cars[]" required>`'

Note the use of "cars[]" for the name.

This allows me to have multiple inputs with the same name.

I would like to get the answers from all the inputs in JavaScript.

How can this be done?

I have the following WRONG code for this:

```
var element = document.getInput("cars[]");
for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  alert(element[i].value);
}
```

Comment: getElementsByName or querySelectorAll...

Comment: document.getElementsByName("cars[]") ?

Comment: What JavaScript code do you have/?

Comment: My javascript code is:

Comment: var element = document.getInput("cars[]");
   for(i=0; i<element.length;i++){
   alert(element[i].value);
   }

Comment: Well where did you find out about `getInput` since that is not JS Method.

Comment: @tucuxi Um, why did you pick me out on a question that is over 6 years old. And your comment makes little sense.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can give same id to all inputs like

```
<input type="text" id="inputId" name="cars[]" required>'
```

In Javascript iterate the element to get the value

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("cars[]");
for(i=0; i<element.length;i++){
console.log(element[i].value);
}
```

Comment: You can't do that, IDs are unique and JavaScript will only pick up on the first one even if you have more. Also, it would be `document.querySelectorAll("#inputId");` if you could have more than 1 element with the same ID.

Comment: Yaa I have also used document.querySelectorAll, If you use document.querySelector then only it will pick the first one.

Comment: You could give it a `class` or select it by the `name` attribute?

Comment: You are right. I can use either class by giving class name or name attribute. but using Id also we can do it. Is it wrong approach?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I cannot have an id added to the input and would only like to get with the name. Is that possible?

Comment: That is invalid HTML, and a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `document.getElementsByName()` like this:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByName("cars[]");
for(i=0; i<element.length;i++){
 alert(element[i].value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="cars[]" value="a" required>
<input type="text" name="cars[]" value="b" required>
<input type="text" name="cars[]" value="c" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

These two things in pure JavaScript net approximately the same result. The first is using the HTML form element to find all of the input elements attached to it. However, the syntax for finding the array called "cars[]" is troublesome and in my opinion a tad annoying. If I was going to do something in pure JavaScript I'd probably prefer the second way, using `document.querySelectorAll`.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('thing');
  form.elements['cars[]'].forEach(function(el, i) {
    console.log("value is ", el.value)
  }); //Form.elements[] array has been available since Chrome 7 or so. It should be available for use in just about any browser available.
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('[name="cars[]"]');
  items.forEach(function(el, i) {
    console.log("Item Value is ", el.value)
  });

});
```

```html
<form id="thing">
  <input type="text" name="cars[]" value="1" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="cars[]" value="2" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="cars[]" value="3" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="cars[]" value="4" />
  <br />

  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, input type="text" not checkbox

Comment: then change them to type text, it doesn't do anything to the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You write

> Note the use of "cars[]" for the name.
> This allows me to have multiple inputs with the same name.

In HTML, **you can have many inputs in the same form with the same name, regardless of that name having a `[]` suffix or not**. This has always been used for, say, checkboxes. Most server-side libraries will then return the values for those inputs as an array.

An example of gathering all values for inputs with a given name could be the following:

```js
document.querySelector("#b").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const values = [];
  document.querySelectorAll("input[name='color']").forEach(e => values.push(e.value));
  console.log(values); // outputs ["foo", "bar", "baz"] if values unchanged
});
```

```css
input { display: block; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<label>Enter your favorite colors
 <input type="text" name="color" value="foo"/>
 <input type="text" name="color" value="bar"/>
 <input type="text" name="color" value="baz"/>
</label>

<label>
 Enter your favorite food
 <input type="text" name="food" value="flub"/>
</label>

<button id="b">Click me to output favorite colors</button>
```